# How to stop IDEA auto completing variable name suggestions

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I've been a user of IntelliJ IDEA for the last 7/8 years on both Windows and Linux. I've recently upgraded from 12 to 13, but also moved to MacOSX.

I don't recall this being a major issue previously, so I'm not sure if it previously occurred, is a new feature of IntelliJ 13, or is a feature of the MacOSX release.Either way, it's bugging the hell out of me now.

When I'm coding, IntelliJ suggests names for variables and, since I'm just typing, it then completes the var name immediately without me scanning the suggestion.

I'm all for autocompletion of code, or parameters as mostly, I've expected the auto-completion and am monitoring what's going on. Also, in fairness there is nothing wrong with the suggested var names. However it's happening without my knowledge or expectation and I then need to stop what I'm doing and see what happened.

My workflow comes to a jarring halt as I rescan what I've just typed and see what IntelliJ changed.

For instance, I am typing

```
...
HttpURLConnection tConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
...
```

however, as I type `tConn<Space>=`, IntelliJ has suggested and selected `connecton` as a replacement for `tConn`. As I said, nothing *incorrect* (in fairness, better var naming anyway), but now I go to use `tConn` and it's not there. I need to search through the code to see IntelliJ's change.

Does anyone know of a way to turn *just this* off in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got same problem with you, and I've found a great option for this problem.

`Settings > Editor > Code Completion` The one below `Autopopup code completion`, it's called `Insert selected variant by typing dot, space, etc.`

@Bas Leijdekkers is almost correct.

Comment: Thanks. Wow, I'd forgotten this query. 2+ years old. Do you turn this option on or off?

Comment: Sorry for replying soooo late... I've turned it off because I can always select what I want by pressing enter...

Comment: Meanwhile, it moved to Settings > Editor > General > Code Completion > Insert selected suggestion by pressing space, dot, or other context-dependent keys

Answer (score 0):

Disable `Autopopup code completion` in `Settings > Editor > Code Completion`

Comment: But I want code completion for everything _except_ variables names

Comment: If you disable "autopopup", you can still invoke it manually everywhere you want. Use Ctrl+Space for basic completion and Ctrl+Shift+Space for type completion.